# Javascript ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with this line of code?

```
req.body.location && req.body.location.type = 'Point'
```

I just want to add a type property but I got error

> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

but this will work

```
if(req.body.location) req.body.location.type = 'Point'
```

Just curious isn't both statement means the same why the first one doesn't work?

Comment: Try `req.body.location && (req.body.location.type = 'Point')`.

Comment: For me in `console` it is working. @CertainPerformance You can also flip it `req.body.location.type = 'Point' && req.body.location`. Not?

Comment: The Node.js `req` will be always there. For the second line. [Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/c98ay1bb/1/) @CertainPerformance

Comment: You're right, I was confusing a linter error with a syntax error, sorry. Still not something that should be done, though.

Comment: Yeah. Looks code-saving though. [It works by the way due to `precedence`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) `()` got the highest `precedence` of 20. `&&` only a `precedence` of 6. @CertainPerformance

Comment: @AjAX. so why `&&` throw error in node? or I'm confused btw jsx and node? but `&&` is not jsx it's a part of js. Why need `()`?

Comment: Because `&&` got a higher `precedence` than `=`. So it compares and then gets stuck at the `=` assigning. `()` got the highest `precedence` and makes the right block seen as 1. So it works best.

Comment: when to use `&&` with `()`? in jsx I don't have to do that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: use `req.body.location && (req.body.location.type = 'Point')`

They're not the same statement. Here's a similar but complete example:

```
const foo = {};
foo && foo.bar = 'baz';
```

Let's break this down by [order precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).
&& is level 6 and = is level 3 on the order of operations, so && takes preference.
Thus this part of the code runs first: `foo && foo.bar`.
`foo && foo.bar` evaluates to undefined - let's not worry about the particulars right now.
So what you end up with is: `undefined = 'baz'`

and that is not allowed. You cannot redefine `undefined` in javascript.

Now let's consider this code:

```
const foo = {};
if (foo) {
  foo.bar = 'baz';
}
```

The if expression takes precedence, followed by the assignment.

To fix your original statement, you could add parenthesis around the && operation. This has nothing to do with JS or JSX, simply how javascript works.

Given `foo && (foo.bar = 'baz')`
First, the parenthesis take precedence at level 20. This is like making a placeholder variable that doesn't get executed yet. Something like this:

```
const runLater = () => (foo.bar = 'baz');
foo && runLater()
```

Obviously that's not what happens exactly due to scope issues, but pseudocode wise you're collapsing the statement into a placeholder.

Now we have `foo && runLater()`. Now the normal && logic applies. It executes the left side, and if true, the right side. So runLater() then sets foo.bar to be baz. It's a little tricky to think about because parenthesis take higher precedence, but to create this kind of placeholder.